# Why is my responsive layout broken?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Here's the page: http://www.thresholds.org.uk/museums-collections-poets/kettles-yard/

It looks great in Chrome even when you resize the browser, everything looks great. However, in Firefox, columns overlap one another and images don't resize.

The main grid classes are .c-1 (the smaller width column) and .c-2 (the width of two .c-1 columns). Whats going on in my code to cause this problem?

For quick reference, I'm using CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box` for my grid, here's the code for my .c-1 and .c-2 classes:

```
.c-1 {
width: 288px;
float: left;
margin-left: 28px;
display: block;
}

.c-2 {
width: 604px;
float: left;
margin-left: 28px;
display: block;
}

.c-1:first-child, .c-2:first-child, .c-1:nth-child(4n+1) { margin-left: 0; }
```

I'm also using the following code for responsive images:

```
img { 
border: 0; 
-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
vertical-align: middle; 
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-bottom: 1.875em;
}
```

**EDIT** Ok I've seemed to have fixed the responsive images for most sections now. A classname of .active was missing a width value but I've still got a crazy problem with the Blog section. Even though the same layout has been used on that page (.c-1 and .c-2 inline together) this section seems to overlap one another...odd!

Comment: Hi, please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997) thanks!

Comment: I've added the key bits of code now @Pekka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well it seems Firefox doesn't like calculating widths of elements when these elements don't have a width specified, which explains why responsive images were not working. *An image set to max-width must have a container with a set width otherwise images won't scale.*

I thought browsers defaulted elements to 100% width, if a width hasn't been specified in the CSS?

Anyways, all fixed now. Put widths on your wrappers people!